# System No Boot no video after failed BIOS update

Tags: bios, flashing

I have a HCL Me Series M54 Laptop.

I downloaded the .NRG BIOS update file from [here](http://www.hclsupportservice.in/DriversDisplay.jsp?val=Tm90ZWJvb2s=&prodC=TUUgTGFwdG9w&prodM=Series%2054), and tried to flash the BIOS.

The update stuck at 48%:

[image]

..and then when I restarted, there is no display, the system boots for 6 seconds then fan speed increases for 5 seconds then the system restarts on its own and then in next boot the system shuts down within 3-4 seconds.

No beeps, no display hence no error message, when the above is happening just the power and the WiFi LEDs light up, and then if I restart then the entire cycle repeats.

I need help in what to do. I removed the CMOS battery, tried to remove flea power etc still no-go.

Comment: You have corrupted your firmware by turning your laptop off in the middle of a firmware flash.  You will need to replace the motherboard to solve this problem.

Comment: Agree with @Ramhound, that warning in red at the bottom is there for good reason. The Basic Input/Output System (BIOS) is the very first part a computer runs through in order to actually boot. If this system is damaged, the machine is essentially a brick. Some research is not showing any reversion process or back-up BIOS on this unit. I'm sorry.

Comment: Only a very small subset of motherboards have a fail-safe firmware feature if the primary is corrupted.  I have only seen `desktop replacement` laptops have this feature due to their design choices of using actual desktop motherboards.

Answer (score 0):

When you are working with the BIOS you have to be really careful if you're going to upgrade it. The computer doesn't need human intervention when flashing the BIOS (unless the system ask for your intervention), this is because it could be **seriously harmed** (that's the reason of the warning at the bottom of the screen). Manufacturers such as TOSHIBA, Lenovo and hp allows you to upgrade your BIOS using a software flash tool that does the job for you, and that's a very safe method (by experience).
On the other hand, it's higly recommended to do nothing during the process, it could take around a half-hour, but you still don't need to touch anything and let the computer do the job until it restarts itself and you can see your O.S. screen again.

Comment: [Here's](http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/downloads/migr-70350) some really useful information, it's from the Lenovo website, but it's very useful.